# Webpack 4 output CSS to different folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack4

Не получается при билде поместить CSS в отдельную папку. Знаю проблему совместимости webpack 4 и extract-text-webpack-plugin. Но также применил следующее решение:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/694#issuecomment-362549892

Но все равно не работает. Выплевывает следующую ошибку:

[image: webpack 4 extract-text-webpack-plugin issue]

Подскажите ваше решение.

Пример кода:

```js
const sassETP = new ExtractTextPlugin({
 filename: getPath => {
  return getPath('css/styles.css');
 },
});

  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    use: sassETP.extract({
     use: [
      "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
      "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
      "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
     ]
    }),
   },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить fallback: 'style-loader'

```js
rules: [
   {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    use: sassETP.extract({
     fallback: "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
     use: [
      "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
      "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
     ]
    }),
   },
  ],
```